# Look for list of words in a sentence in Go

Tags: go

In python I have code like this

```
search_words_nonTexas = ["tx", "texas", "houston"]
pass = any(word in title for word in search_words_nonTexas)
```

in Go, I have been trying this

```
firstPass := strings.ContainsAny("title", searchWordsNonTexas)
```

Im getting an error (show below) about the arguments not being right. What would be the equivalent in Go ?

```
cannot use searchWordsNonTexas (type [10]string) as type string in 
argument to strings.ContainsAny
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In python I have code. What would be the equivalent in Go?

---

In Go, a lower-level language, write your own function.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "unicode"
)

// Look for list of words in a sentence.
func WordsInSentence(words []string, sentence string) []string {
    var in []string

    dict := make(map[string]string, len(words))
    for _, word := range words {
        dict[strings.ToLower(word)] = word
    }

    f := func(r rune) bool { return !unicode.IsLetter(r) }
    for _, word := range strings.FieldsFunc(sentence, f) {
        if word, ok := dict[strings.ToLower(word)]; ok {
            in = append(in, word)
            delete(dict, word)
        }
    }

    return in
}

func main() {
    words := []string{"tx", "texas", "houston"}
    sentence := "The Texas song Yellow Rose of Texas was sung in Houston, TX."
    in := WordsInSentence(words, sentence)
    fmt.Println(in)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/CwSLiDnq928

Output:

```
[texas houston tx]
```